# what was reason to get different o/p when i run code in pycharm and terminal?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I type this code

```
import pokitdok
print dir(pokitdok)
```

in terminal I got below output

```
['__author__', '__builtins__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__title__', '__version__', 'absolute_import', 'api', 'pokitdok']
```

But when i run same  code in Pycharm i got below error

```
  'Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/rponnapureddy/Desktop/ramnath/pok.py", line 3, in <module>
   import pokitdok
   File "/home/rponnapureddy/Desktop/ramnath/pokitdok.py", line 28, in      <module>
    import simplejson as json
    ImportError: No module named simplejson '
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have all of the libraries installed. My guess is that your python that is running without error is not the same python that pycharm is running. You would have to check your settings and see if you can point pycharm to your python. Otherwise use pip to install simplejson in pycharm.

```
pip install simplejson
```

Comment: after install  pip install simplejson i got below error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rponnapureddy/Desktop/ramnath/pok.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pokitdok
  File "/home/rponnapureddy/Desktop/ramnath/pokitdok.py", line 30, in <module>
    url = json.loads(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 505, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode

Comment: line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: I am using sam3 2.7.6 versions in both  terminal and pycharm also

Comment: Maybe the library has an error or somewhere something isn't passing a valid parameter. It might be easier to point pycharm to your working python location.